# What is wrong with my Matlab code? Index out of bounds

Tags: matlab, filter, nmea, kalman-filter

I'm trying to read in a text file that contains nmea strings! But I get

```
??? Attempted to access y(1); index out of bounds because numel(Longitude)=0.
Error in ==> filter at 16
Loc(:,i)=coordinates(x(i),y(i))';
```

filter.m

```
clear all
A=textread('xxx\x.txt','%s','headerlines',1);
 for i=1:30;
n=2*i-1;
A(i)=A(n);
end
b=A(1:30,:);
c=char(b);
x=c(:,17:24);
y=c(:,28:36);
```

I can't figure out why it is wrong?!!

Comment: to avoid name-collision, I would rename your script file to something other than `filter.m` (there is a built-in MATLAB function by that name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cut out the wrong part of the string and end up with the `,N,` part in the beginning (and also no decimals). I believe you want

```
Longitude=c(:,31:42);%Extract Longitude Array
```

Comment: ya! I'm so stupid! just figured it out! thanks!!

Comment: You are also cutting off data in what i can only presume to be wrong with the latitude part. You should double check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Longitude=c(:,28:36);%Extract Longitude Array
```

My guess is that `c(:,28:36)` is empty which implies `A` might be empty too.

Answer (score 0):

`A` is empty. Use [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) instead:

```
>> fid = fopen('C:\Users\myself\Desktop\2.txt', 'rt');
>> A = textscan(fid, '%s');
>> A = A{1};
>> fclose(fid);
```